# In Visual Studio 2010, can you auto-generate an eventhandler in the same way as C#, using Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, shortcut

For example, you can type `this.Loaded +=` in C# and press TAB a couple of times to automatically generate an event handler. Is there an equivelent in Visual Basic?

Typing `Addhandler Me.Loaded` and pressing TAB or RETURN does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VB.NET IDE has a different approach, inspired by the WithEvents keyword.  Note the two combo boxes at the top of the editor window.  You select the (*class* Events) in the upper left, the event you want to subscribe in the upper right combo.  That auto-generates the event handler, it has the Handles keyword.

No help for explicit AddHandler statements that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I miss this feature too, but you can still autogenerate the method with correct parameters like this:

Type it out this far

```vb
AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf DesiredName
```

and then press [STRG + .] to open up the "potential fixes" context menu and hit Return. (The cursor needs to touch the "DesiredName" string for this to work. (No trailing whitespace))